# Zsh alias not working, but command does work when pasted in terminal

Tags: bash, git, zsh, zshrc

I have an alias in my `.zshrc` file, called "housekeeping" like so:

```
alias housekeeping="git fetch -p && git branch -vv | grep ': gone]' | awk '{print $1}' | xargs git branch -d"
```

When I run this command, for some reason, I get the following output:

```
error: The branch '12795-add-ship-info-to-FAQ' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D 12795-add-ship-info-to-FAQ'.
error: branch '97167bb3f' not found.
error: branch '[origin/12795-add-ship-info-to-FAQ:' not found.
error: branch 'gone]' not found.
error: branch 'Edits' not found.
error: branch 'to' not found.
error: branch 'text' not found.
```

It looks like it's passing down the wrong arguments.

However when I run the exact same command directly from the terminal, I do get the desired result.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Not sure if that's your problem, but you have to escape `$1` in the awk command to `\$1`, or it'll be set when you declare the alias (most likely to the empty string) as it is double quoted overall.

Comment: `xargs` treats each whitespace-delimited word from its input, not necessarily an entire line, as an argument by default.

Comment: You should be defining a function, not an alias, which would make the problem Benjamin W. points out go away.

Comment: Thanks guys, that was indeed the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that inside the double quotes of your alias, `$1` refers to the current first positional parameter of your shell. It's probably not set, so your alias is equivalent to

```
alias housekeeping="... | awk '{print }' | xargs ..."
```

after `$1` expands to the empty string. As a result, the entire output of `grep`, not just the branch name, is fed to `xargs`, which treats *any* whitespace, not just newlines, as separating two arguments.

You either need to escape the dollar sign (`awk '{print \$1}'`) to make sure `awk` gets the correct script, or better yet, use a *function* instead of an alias to avoid the extra layer of quotes.

```
housekeeping () {
  git fetch -p && git branch -vv | awk '/: gone]/ {print $1}' | xargs git branch -d
}
```

Note that I've replace the call to `grep` with a pattern in the `awk` script.

Comment: Fantastic, thanks so much for explaining that to me!